# Mac keyboard shortcut for Alt+4 now resolving to ¢

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos

I am not sure how to google for this problem.

I recently upgrade OS:X and had a crash and I lost the ability to do my <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> shortcut to move spaces. I instead get the <kbd>¢</kbd> character.

My shortcut setting is set in preferences:

[image]

I am not sure where to override the (new) keyboard shortcut for the <kbd>¢</kbd> key. The other shortcuts for spaces work (ie switching to desktop 1-3).

This was working prior to a system crash.

I have re-added my keyboard that I am using, which does not fix the problem. I have the same problem on my built-in keyboard as well as my USB keyboard.

Comment: Do you have a keyboard with a 10-key pad? Shortcuts differentiate between 10-key & the numbers above qwerty. Either test using alt/4 on the 10-key, or just remove the shortcut & re-add it using the 4 above qwerty.

Comment: @Tetsujin I do not have a 10-key pad on either.

Comment: OS X normally uses alt for special characters.  So on a US keyboard alt 12345 are ¡™£¢∞.  Shortcuts would normally use Control, with Control 1 (^1) the default for Switch to Desktop 1.   That's not good for you?

Comment: @TomGewecke sure, but that doesn't explain why this was working fine prior to a system crash and now is not working (?).

Answer (score 1):

I used [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and added a custom shortcut:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Override alt4</name>
    <identifier>private.always_send_four</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::4, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::4, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

I then bound my actual spaces shortcut to <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>.